# Trace two DateListPlots?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, date-and-time

I currently have two DateListPlots in the same graph, with two different y-axes. I downloaded the package "TwoAxisDateListPlot" to accomplish this with ease. Now I want to be able to trace both of the curves so I can match up their data points. Here's what I've got so far:

```
data = Import["file.csv", "CSV"]
data2 = Import["file2.csv", "CSV"]
TwoAxisDateListPlot[data,data2,Joined->True,PlotLegends->{"Vbat","Temp"}]
```

This is the graph:

[image]

I'm guessing I should use a Manipulate function for this, but I'm just not that great at using Mathematica yet. Thanks for the help.

EDIT: By "trace," I mean show individual points of the graphs by using a slider to move a point along the curve. Like the trace button on TI calculators. But I'm not sure how I'd do that since the x values are dates.

Comment: What do you mean by "trace"?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have that package installed, but I will give you an example which can surly be extended to your situation. The basic principle should be clear: You want to select (by `Slider` or whatever) a certain time and then plot this point dynamically over your `DateListPlot`. Let's say we have a simple plot of financial data like this

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

My approach will extract the drawn points from this graphics and gives you the opportunity to *trace* them. First, you need to understand how *Mathematica* draws such graphs and this is why I want you to look at the internal representation of a very simple plot. The first part of each `Graphics` are the graphics primitives which define what is plotted. Look at this

```
data = {{{2006, 10, 1}, 10}, {{2006, 10, 15}, 12}, 
  {{2006, 10, 30}, 15}, {{2006, 11, 20}, 20}};
DateListPlot[data][[1]]
```

and see that beside setting some colors, the curve is drawn with a `Line` primitive. Therefore, what I will do is use `Cases` to extract the expression matching `Line[pts_]` in the plot. Then I will use these points and put it inside a `Manipulate`. For convenience, I will extract the currently used point, max, min, ... values, so that I don't have to write `pts[[...]]` over and over again.

The rest is to create a new graphics that shows the current point, two helping lines and a label. Everything is then put together with the original plot using `Show`. I have inserted empty lines in the code, so that you can see the single steps I have explained:

```
With[{dlp = DateListPlot[FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2004"]]},
 With[{pts = First@Cases[dlp, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity]},

  Manipulate[

   Module[{mint, maxt, minv, maxv, t, v},
    {{mint, maxt}, {minv, maxv}} = {Min[#], Max[#]} & /@ Transpose[pts];
    {t, v} = pts[[i]];

    Show[dlp,

     Graphics[{ColorData[5, 2], Thickness[.005], PointSize[0.02], 
       Line[{{mint, v}, {t, v}, {t, 0}}], Point[{t, v}],
       Text[Style[DateString[t, {"DateShort"}] <> ": " <> ToString[v], 12,
          Background -> Opacity[.7, White]], {t, v}, {-1, -2}]}]
     ]],

   {i, 1, Length[pts], 1}]
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]